# Grid "auto-fit" not wrapping the element when size getting smaller

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to achieve the "auto-fit" with `grid` layout. But not works. how to get it work?

requirement: when the screen size getting smaller, the links should wrap in to multiple column(s).

here is my html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
        <a href="#">Link3</a>
        <a href="#">Link4</a>
        <a href="#">Link5</a>
        <p>@copyright goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
  max-width: 480px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0 20px;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(auto-fit, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

a{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

p{
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: span 5;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/X0kZi95bQ1VoA0nC?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: i can  make it...but you need to put `p` out side of `.container` ....that means  you need to put `p` tag in `.wrapper` div

Comment: @noo - it will move out of grid. in case if I like to add more column in second row, how to do?

Comment: you put  copy right text as new one row (from your live demo link)... also you can use `display:grid;` to `.wrapper` class

Comment: the value is invalid, you something like `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px,1fr))` .. you cannot use auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif - can you please share in demo? I am not able to create

Comment: simply change this `repeat(auto-fit, auto)` by the value I gave you

Comment: @TemaniAfif - not works : https://plnkr.co/edit/X0kZi95bQ1VoA0nC?open=lib%2Fscript.js - as well how to keep min width as auto? since i don't know the width of text of links?

Comment: make the p `grid-column: 1/-1;` instread of the span 5

Comment: Yes works. thanks. to help some one please post as answer. But still I am not find the answer for - l how to keep min width as auto? since i don't know the width of text of links?

Comment: you cannot do this with grid, you can do it with flexbox (which can easily do this) but based on your comment below you don't want to use it

Answer (score -1):

You can instead use display flex to achieve the wrapping of your links when the screen size gets smaller.

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to your `.container` class after adding display flex will be able to make your links wrap when the screen size is smaller.

Comment: I did not use any flex container.

Comment: It will be much easier if you convert to display flex for wrapping of your content

Comment: if you go for larger screen, all this is going to be single row. please understand